# How to copy a folder to multiple folders using command line?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want to copy a specific folder from one point to another and I have more the 300 destination folder where I want to copy that specific folder.
Can anybody assist me with a proper solution? 
shell script suggestion would be great.

Comment: Where do you have the list of destinations?

Comment: You might also want to consider using a symlink (`ln - s`) instead of copying, depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming your first folder is called `foo` and you want to copy it to directories, which are specified in `destinations.txt` (one per line).

You could use a `for`-loop for this:

```
for i in $(cat destinations.txt)
do
  echo "$i" #prints the name of the current target -> you can see progress, if it takes long  
  cp -R foo/ "$i"
done
```

Comment: @santoshkale please consider using the solution given in [steeldriver's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/795542/85695) instead of this. This one will break if any of your target names contains spaces or any other type of whitespace. It will also break if they start with a `-` and on various other edge cases. In general, it is never a good idea to use `for i in $(cat file)` it's always better to use `while read i ... < file` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right - that is probably the better way

Answer (score 12):

I'd suggest using a `while ... do` loop

```
while read -r d; do
  cp -R -- foo/ "$d"
done < destinations.txt
```

---

Alternatively, using `xargs`

```
xargs -n1 -a destinations.txt cp -R foo --
```

Comment: If the source directory is big, is it safe if I run many copy commands in many terminals at the same time? Each terminal is for one destination.

Answer (score 3):

The core of a function I have in my `.bashrc` for this is this:

```
echo $destinations | xargs -n 1 cp $sourcefile
```

(I think I got that from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/195972/919057)) If the destinations are in `destinations.txt`, just replace `echo $destinations` with `cat destinations.txt` Filenames with spaces will give you issues unless they're quoted in the input, so be wary of that.

Here's the full function from my `.bashrc`. Probably not very robust, as my use cases were simple and I didn't want to spend long on it, so don't expect it to handle weirder filenames very gracefully.

```
function distribute {
        arguments=""
        destinations=""
        sourcefile=""
        while [[ $# -ge 1 ]]; do
                key="$1"

                if [[ "$key" == "-h" ]]; then
                        echo "usage: $0 [flags to cp] source_file destination_1 [... destination_N]"
                elif [[ "$key" == -* ]]; then
                        arguments+=" $key"
                elif [ -z "$sourcefile" ]; then
                        sourcefile="$key"
                else
                        destinations+=" $key"
                fi

                shift
        done

        echo $destinations | xargs -n 1 cp $arguments $sourcefile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -r sourceFolder {destination1,destination2,destination14}
```